# Adjust fade on pc

Tags: pc, audio, audio-adapters

I know this question is vague but I'm trying to find a way to connect regular speakers with red and black connectors to my PC and be able to adjust fade (front and back), in addition to balance, for four speakers.

Please suggest any hardware or software required to do so.

At this time, it does not need to be OS specific.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to say this is too broad. There's just too many solutions available, and since you noted that a software solution would be fine, hardwarerecs probably isn't the place to ask this. That said, superuser might be a good place.

Comment: On that note: "Regular red and black connectors." Are you referring to RCA cables? What are you plugging them into (if "your PC", what PC/motherboard?) OS specific software solutions are going reign, so what OS are you using?

Comment: The red and black wires on the back of car and home speakers. I'm looking into building a car PC and am in the planning phase. I haven't settled on an OS yet because I don't know which hardware I'll be using. The only thing I haven't figured out is what hardware has drivers which allow for adjusting audio fade like.

Comment: The problem is there's just too many ways to accomplish what you want to do: hardware controls, software, sound card dependent... basically whatever you do, there will be a way to accomplish it. Think of it this way: in the end, all you're doing is changing the amplitude of two sets of signals. The number of ways you can do that is innumerable.

Comment: What OS or driver do you know of that supports this feature? To my knowledge the OS leaves it to the driver to implement this. I chose hardware reqs because drivers are hardware specific. If I can find the hardware and driver that will accomplish my goal then I can look at which OS's are supported by that driver.